# React looping over Map vs Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got an issue where I am trying to loop over a map and return a `<p>` element in each case. It isn't working as I believe it should, however it is working for an array.

The code is as follows:

```
  <div className="previousRounds">
    {myTestMap.forEach(() => (
      <p>I've looped over a map to print this</p> //This doesn't work
    ))}

    {currentUsersPicks.map(() => (
      <p>I've looped over an array to print this</p> //This works
    ))}

  </div>
```

The map definitely exists and if I replace the `<p></p>` tags with `console.log` then I do get output printed to the console.

Here's a screenshot of the webpage.

So why does this work for an array and not a map?

Expecting this to work whether it's a map or array

Comment: [`forEach` doesn't return anything](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach#return_value). It's not that it "works for an array but doesn't for a map" rather that `map` and `forEach`  do different things with the results of their iteration. `map` keeps and returns those results, `forEach` is honey badger.

Comment: `myTestMap` is a `Map` and `currentUsersPicks` is an `Array`, right? `Map` doesn't have a `.map` method so you tried `.forEach`, right? see my post below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map()` method returns a new array, whereas the `forEach()` method does not return a new array. The map() method is used to transform the elements of an array, whereas the forEach() method is used to loop through the elements of an array.

---

###### For Each

The following two code examples produce exactly the same result, you can think of forEach like the first more traditional for loop.

```js
const myArr = ["my", "array", "test"];

for (const word of myArr) console.log(word);

myArr.forEach((word) => console.log(word));
```

###### Map

The following two code examples also produce exactly the same result, you can think of map like the first more traditional approach on mapping.

```js
const myArr = ["my", "array", "test"];

const newArr1 = [];
for (const word of myArr) newArr.push(`${word}-1`);

const newArr2 = myArr.map((word) => `${word}-1`);
```

---

So when you want to render items in react you need to use the map method on the array to return a new array containing your JSX. Here is an example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const names = ["John", "Sarah", "Mike"];
  return (
    <ul>
      {names.map((name) => {
        return <li key={name}>{name}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

You should always provide a key to your repeated JSX item, you can learn more about keys and why react uses them [here](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists).

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` returns `undefined` which produces no JSX. Your `map` actually returns some JSX so that's why it renders.

If you change your callback in map to not use a return it will not render anything either:

```js
array.map(() => {
   <p>I've looped over an array to print this</p>
})
```

Comment: don't forget the `key` prop

Answer (score 0):

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) doesn't have a `.map` method, instead it gives you access to its data using iterators. You can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [myMap.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys), [myMap.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), or [myMap.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) to produce an array. Conveniently, `Array.from` accepts a mapping function as second argument -

```js
function App() {
  const myTestMap = new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]])
  return Array.from(
    myTestMap.entries(),
    ([key, value]) => <pre key={key}>{key}, {value}</pre>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```css
pre { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```